# Slowly auto scroll to the bottom of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, autoscroll

I'm trying to have my div start slowly scrolling down to the bottom of the div but can't seem to get that to work. I can get my div to scroll to the bottom immediately but I want it to take some time. The code for the scrolling I have right now is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myDiv').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#myDiv').get(0).scrollHeight
            }, "slow");
        });
    </script>
```

The code for my div is

```
<div class="ASIProfile right" style="overflow:auto; height: 160px;" id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using an integer instead of "slow" to test different scrolling speeds to see if any variations give the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#myDiv').get(0).scrollHeight
            }, 1500);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ASIProfile right" style="overflow:auto; height: 1600px;" id="myDiv">
div 1 ( auto scroll to bottom smoothly )
</div>
<div class="ASIProfile right" style="overflow:auto; height: 160px;" id="myDaiv">
div 2
</div>
```